# SELECT JOIN Table Operations

Tags: sql

In my query below, I joined tables b, c, d to a by the base_id column. 
However, I need to do some operations in my SELECT statement.
Since b, c, and d are not joined to each other,

is my `(a.qty - (b.qty - (c.qty + d.qty)))` formula computing only those tables that have the same base_id column?

```
SELECT (a.qty - (b.qty - (c.qty + d.qty))) AS qc_in 
  FROM receiving a
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty, base_id 
        FROM quality_control bb
       WHERE location_to = 6 
         AND is_canceled = 0 
       GROUP BY base_id
      ) b
         ON b.base_id = a.base_id
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty, base_id 
        FROM quality_control ba
       WHERE location_from = 6
         AND is_canceled = 0
       GROUP BY base_id
      ) c
         ON c.base_id = a.base_id
  LEFT JOIN ( 
     SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty, base_id
       FROM issuance
      WHERE location_from = 6
        AND is_canceled = 0
      GROUP BY base_id
      ) d
         ON d.base_id = a.base_id
 WHERE a.is_canceled = 0
```

Comment: I think you want `(a.qty - (b.qty - (c.qty + d.qty)))`

Comment: Please don't tag spam. I removed the tags for various DBMS. Please only tag the one you're using.

Comment: @Nick yes you are right, my bad.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the  [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are actually using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I think this could be simplified massively by using conditional aggregation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you mean by conditional aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused by how joining works (if I'm reading the question correctly). If you have:

```
select *
from table1 a
join table2 b 
    on a.Id = b.Id
join table3c
    on a.Id = c.Id
```

Then yes a is joined to b, and b is joined to c, but that also means that a is joined to c. One way to think of it is as one giant in-memory table that has all of the a columns then all of the b columns and then all of the c columns in the one result.

If a.Id is 1, and you select the row from b where Id is the same (1) and then you join to c where the Id is the same as a (1), then a, b and c all have the same id.

So yes, `(a.qty - (b.qty - (c.qty + d.qty)))` will only be doing that calculation for rows where a, b, c and d all have the same `base_id` .

Answer (score 0):

Surely. In the nested statements you join all the tables on `base_id`. That means, as the result of those joins you will get a huge table containing columns from all of the joined tables with a common column you join on (`base_id` in your case).